# Split string into two parts

Tags: javascript

I know there are several ways to split an array in jQuery but I have a special case:
If I have for example this two strings:

```
 "G09.4 What"
 "A04.3  A new Code"
```

When I split the first by `' '` I can simply choose the code in front with `[0]` what would be `G09.4`. And when I call `[1]` I get the text: `What`

But when I do the same with the second string I get for `[1]` `A` but I want to retrieve `A new Code`.

So how can I retrieve for each string the code and the separate text?

Comment: var newStr=""; for(var i=1; i<splitArr.length; i++){ newStr+=splitArr[i]+" " }

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use

```
var someString = "A04.3  A new Code";
var index = someString.indexOf(" ");  // Gets the first index where a space occours
var id = someString.slice(0, index); // Gets the first part
var text = someString.slice(index + 1);  // Gets the text part
```

Comment: Sorry but somehow it wont work in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/aJZZw/1/

Comment: Fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/aJZZw/2/

Comment: @JohnSmith Have eddited my answer, had a small bug. Changed the line `var text = someString.substr(index + 1);`

Answer (score 12):

You can split the string and shift off the first entry in the returned array. Then join the leftovers e.g.

```
var chunks = "A04.3  A new Code".split(/\s+/);
var arr = [chunks.shift(), chunks.join(' ')];

// arr[0] = "A04.3"
// arr[1] = "A new Code"
```

Comment: I bet you go dynamite fishing. That's joust overkill.

Comment: Felt it's look overkill, but easy to understand, so used in project.

Comment: Are you sure the comma is a sequence point?  what if some flavor of JS evaluates the array elements in parallel?  I think this behavior is undefined. aka you got lucky

Answer (score 5):

You can use `match()` and capture what you need via a regular expression:

```
"G09.4 What".match(/^(\S+)\s+(.+)/)
  // => ["G09.4 What", "G09.4", "What"]

"A04.3  A new Code".match(/^(\S+)\s+(.+)/)
  // => ["A04.3  A new Code", "A04.3", "A new Code"]
```

As you can see the two items you want are in `[1]` and `[2]` of the returned arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting the string on the space, use a combination of `indexOf` and `slice`:

```
var s = "A04.3 A new Code";
var i = s.indexOf(' ');
var partOne = s.slice(0, i).trim();
var partTwo = s.slice(i + 1, s.length).trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this one:

```
function split2(str, delim) {
    var parts=str.split(delim);
    return [parts[0], parts.splice(1,parts.length).join(delim)];
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QLuy3/)

Or for more performance, try this:

```
function split2s(str, delim) {
    var p=str.indexOf(delim);
    if (p !== -1) {
        return [str.substring(0,p), str.substring(p+1)];
    } else {
        return [str];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code and then remove it from the original string leaving you with both the code and the string without the code.

```
var originalString = "A04.3  A new Code",
    stringArray = originalString.split(' '),
    code,
    newString;

code = stringArray[0];
newString = originalString.replace(code, '');
```